# Getting value of ? wildcard in Excel

Tags: excel, macos, ms-office

I am building a revision timetable for some exams, so have a calendar set up I have made. I list each revision session in the format `[hh:mm] subject` (for example, `[01:30] Maths`). I then have another sheet which uses `COUNTIF` to count the number of sessions for each subject, using `=COUNTIF(Timetable!D3:J37, "[??:??] subject")`. What I now want to do, is have another column which adds together the values for `[??:??]` so that I can list how long each subject is being revised for. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an "array formula" like this

`=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Maths",Timetable!D3:J37)),MID(Timetable!D3:J37,2,5)+0))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Format result cell to show time values, i.e. [h]:mm

That will sum all time values from cells that contain "Maths" - all those cells must have the time in the same position and format, see example screenshot

[image: Example Table]